# ng-grid cellTemplate issue with background color of cell

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, celltemplate

When I have a value as an empty string "" in the data and I use background color in cellTemplate it does not color enitire cell. Here is the plunke that illustrates the issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/TP4VH9xA7qCFT8xgNKW8?p=preview

Can someone help me fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround, in **cellTemplate** you can check for an empty/null string and add the HTML `&nbsp` (non breaking space) entity, this way your cell will be properly rendered.

**Example:**

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="yellow" ><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)||"&nbsp"}}</div></div>'
```

Changed your plunker, here's a working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/tR6UKCrXZqKi5HwsWOAV?p=preview

Comment: That worked for me, but I have one more problem http://plnkr.co/edit/4IeQQBTIe8sgHVEBUTAp?p=preview , here the row border becomes invisible when I color the entire column.Is there a workaround?

Comment: good question, I'll try to check it out, in any case its better you ask a new question, this way you'll get more response.

Comment: Thank you Ill post a question.